# Removing a java class fom a list

Tags: java, class, list

I have a list full of many classes and in each class I would like to know a way that allows me to remove itself like this:

```
public class World{
    List<Entity> Entities;
}
public class Entity{
    public void removeselffromlist()
    {
        //code i dont know
    }
}
```

Edit:There will not be multiple worlds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to make the list available to the other class. One possible solution would be:

```
public class World {
    List<Entity> entities;

    public void removeItem(Entity entity) {
        entities.remove(entity);
    }
}

public class Entity{
    public void removeSelfFromList() {
        world.removeItem(this);
    }
}
```

Note that you would need to have a "world" object somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to remove itself from the list, the `Entity` class requires a reference to it.  One means of achieving this is to control addition to / removal from the list via public methods on the `World` class; e.g.

```
public class World {
  private final List<Entity> entities;

  public void addEntity(Entity entity) {
    if (entity.getWorld() != null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Entity already associated with a world: " + entity);
    }

    entities.add(entity);
    entity.setWorld(this);
  }

  public void removeEntity(Entity entity) {
    if (entity.getWorld() != this) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Entity is not associated with this world: " + entity);
    }

    entities.remove(entity);
    entity.setWorld(null);
  }
}

public class Entity {
  private World world;

  public World getWorld() { return world; }
  public void setWorld(World world) { this.world = world; }

  public void remove() { 
    world.removeEntity(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: there will not be multiple worlds

Answer (score -1):

While I question this whole approach (without knowing a specific reason why you'd need to do this), the answer is that the `Entity` class would need access to at least a`World` instance, if not the `Entities` list directly. Note that you should be using camelCase; variables should never start with an uppercase letter.

```
public class World{
    private List<Entity> myEntities;

    public void addEntity(Entity e)
    {
        myEntities.add(e);
        e.setWorld(this);
    }

    public void removeEntity(Entity e)
    {
        myEntities.remove(e);
    }    

}
public class Entity{

    private World myWorld;

    public setWorld(World w)
    {
        this.myWorld = w;
    }

    public void removeselffromlist()
    {
        //code i dont know
        myWorld.removeEntity(this);
    }
}
```

If I were doing something like this, I'd move all creation, ownership and management of `Entity` objects inside the `World` class.